# Define aiohttp ClientSession on class __init__ for later reuse

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I want to create a persistent session that last until the program ends, I have the following code.

```py
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import atexit

class Session:
    def __init__(self):
        self._session = aiohttp.ClientSession()
        atexit.register(self._close_session)

    async def get(self, url):
        response = await self._session.request("GET", url)
        return await response.json()

    def _close_session(self):
        asyncio.run(self._session.close())


async def pullit():
    print(await session.get("https://raw.communitydragon.org/latest/game/data/characters/aatrox/aatrox.bin.json"))

session = Session()

asyncio.run(pullit()) # THIS THROWS: Timeout context manager should be used inside a task
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(pullit()) #THIS RUNS OK
```

This throws me an exception on the `self._session.request` line with `Timeout context manager should be used inside a task`, I've searched for other answers but it is still giving the same error.

**Question:** What is the cause of this error? If I want to open a session that last the lifetime of a program, and I need it to be defined inside a class (obligatory), how would that be ?

**Extra:** Currently I am using `atexit` to close the session when the program ends (refer above code), is this a *good* way of doing so ? if not, what is a better practice

**UPDATE:** I found the solution to this, it was to use `asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(...)`, but isn't `asyncio.run()` the same as above ? why does one runs without problem and the 3.7+ `asyncio.run()` doesn't run ?

---

**UPDATE 2:** I ended up with the following code:

```py
#runner.py
import aiohttp
import asyncio


class Runner:
    def __init__(self, coro):
        self.coro = coro

    async def run(self):
        session = aiohttp.ClientSession()
        client.start_session(session)
        await self.coro
        client.close_session()
        await session.close()


def run(coro):
    runner = Runner(coro)
    return asyncio.run(runner.run())
```

```py
#client.py
class Client:
    def __init__(self):
        self._session = None

    async def get(self, url):
        response = await self._session.request("GET", url)
        return await response.json()

    def start_session(self, session):
        self._session = session

    def close_session(self):
        self._session = None
```

```py
from .runner import run
from .client import Client

client = Client()

async def pullit():
    print(await client.get("https://raw.communitydragon.org/latest/game/data/characters/aatrox/aatrox.bin.json"))

run(pullit())
```

OK, this runs and everything but after it runs it throws me `RuntimeError: Event loop is closed`, which I never closed a loop.

Comment: Can you edit the question to include a _minimal_ example that _reproduces_ the error? It's not clear how you are instantiating and using the `Session` class.

Comment: This is the minimal example for the _class_, let me include the minimal example of how I use that class, hold a second EDIT: updated

Comment: Please note that your example is still not runnable because it doesn't include all the imports, the URL, etc. I have tried to complement it [as follows](https://pastebin.com/ALUyXLPK), but I cannot reproduce the error you are reporting. Does this version result in the error when you run it? If not, could you please edit the runnable example so that it produces the reported error?

Comment: @user4815162342 Sorry for that !! Now I edited, and this is producing the error as specified ! if I run `asyncio.run` it will fail, while the old `get_event_loop().run_until_complete()` works ...

Comment: Just to say that the session _class_ needs to be instantiated in sinchronous code

Comment: Your latest edit basically invalidates my whole answer, and I still don't understand your design, in particular the distinction between `run` and `pullit`. I'll leave it at that; perhaps someone else can answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution to your problem:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import atexit


class HTTPClient():
    def __init__(self):
        self._session = aiohttp.ClientSession()
        atexit.register(self._shutdown)
        print('session created')

    async def request(self, *args, **kwargs):
        async with self._session.request(*args, **kwargs) as response:
            return (response.status, await response.text())

    def _shutdown(self):
        asyncio.run(self._session.close())
        print('session closed')


async def main():
    http_client = HTTPClient()
    status, text = await http_client.request(url='http://example.com', method='GET')
    print(status)


asyncio.run(main())
```

On the other hand, I guess, the best approach should be some wrapper around the following code:

```
async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    # perform all needed http calls inside
    pass
```